# NLP Search Engine using Python

Tags: python, nlp, search-engine

I have an excel file having two columns, one column has query and other column has solutions of that particular query. I want a search engine so that whenever someone searches for a particular query, top 5 solution should come.

I am new to NLP, please advise how can I do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, show to us what you've been tried. Provide some code to help us to analyze where are you doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, I am not really sure from where to start. Please advice how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, download the data from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AIUAbU-GkPFN0nahRHaK8nV7gtLk68fG

### Dependencies

Using the `transformer` and `nmslib` library:

- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
- https://github.com/nmslib

### To index the data

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import nmslib

import torch
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, DistilBertModel, DistilBertForSequenceClassification

from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

#tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
#model = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')

def vectorize(text):
    input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(text)).unsqueeze(0)
    return model(input_ids)[1].squeeze().detach().numpy()

sentences = []
with open('tatoeba.en-zh') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line.strip():
            en, zh = line.strip().split('\t')
            sentences.append(en)
            sentences.append(zh)

sentences = list(set(sentences)) # Unique list.

# Converts sentences to arrays of floats.
vectorized_sents = [vectorize(s) for s in tqdm(sentences)]

# Concatenate the arrays.
data = np.vstack(vectorized_sents)

# Create the index
index = nmslib.init(method='hnsw', space='cosinesimil')
# Add data to index.
index.addDataPointBatch(data)
# The actual indexing.
index.createIndex({'post': 2}, print_progress=True)
```

### For querying:

```
# When using the index.

# Convert single string to array of floats.
query = vectorize("how fast is the car?")

ids, distances = index.knnQuery(query, k=10) # k=10 means top-10 results
# Results.
for i in ids:
    print(sentences[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is too broad, I can only provide you ways on how you could accomplish this:

The requirement is, for any given new query, the system should be able to retrieve the top 5 solutions from the csv file by matching the corresponding query in the csv.

1. You need to design a text matching approach for this using either **cosine similarity** or **jaccard similarity**. i.e finding the similarity score between the new user query and each and every query present in csv file. You can refer this link for more explanation: https://towardsdatascience.com/overview-of-text-similarity-metrics-3397c4601f50. After this approach, you will have calculated a similarity score between every query in the csv file and the new query. Ideally, you would be having a newly calculated similarity score for every query in the csv file as output.
2. After You've calculated the similarity score between each and every query in csv and the new user query, you can extract the top 5 matching results based on the descending order of similarity score and extract their corresponding solutions.

**The main advantage of this approach is that the new user query need not have to be exactly the same as in the csv file. This approach will also cater to varying sentence formations in the new query.**